# Github pages does not apply CSS file, but it does apply on local host

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I uploaded two files to Github pages: an HTML file and CSS file. When I click on link provided for github pages it only applies HTML. Not CSS file, even though the HMTL and CSS files will apply to local host.

```
!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<H1>Hello world!</H1>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
```

do I have to refer to link CSS and HTML in a different way in order to apply to github pages?
also, there is no file that styles.css is in. And both HTML and CSS files were uploaded not pushed.

Comment: I figured it out for github pages it must be formated with  a ./ , I have href="styles.css"> , if i change it to href="./styles.css">. then github pages can read and refer to that file. this applies to images and js files as well

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path to the css file like:- `/styles.css`

Also at the top it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `!doctype html>`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the GitHub Desktop App to access your files and see if that works.

Here is a tutorial on how to use the desktop app if you have not used it before:
https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/installing-and-configuring-github-desktop/overview/getting-started-with-github-desktop